# GameObject moves in the wrong direction after flipping transform.right

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D game in Unity. I have some GameObjects which should move into the direction of the player.

On start I flip the transform.forward vector into the direction of the player.

```
Vector3 target = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
transform.right = (target - transform.position).normalized;
```

In the editor I can see that the transform.right vector (red arrow) is pointing in the right direction. But when I move the gameobject it moves in the wrong direction if the gameobject is right from the player.

```
rBody.AddForce(Vector2.right * movementSpeed);
```

And I have no idea why? Has anyone any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `AddForce()` which always uses global space in reference to your character. You want to use local space to append your force, so use `AddRelativeForce()`.

Try:

```
rBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.right * movementSpeed);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html

Comment: I tryed AddRelativeForce before but it was the same problem. But I could solve my problem with 

rBody.AddForce(transform.right * movementSpeed);

Answer (score 0):

Changing Vector2.right into transform.right solved my problem

```
rBody.AddForce(transform.right * movementSpeed);
```